# What does this mean? "Requres the gitlab docker runner, with "pass-thru" to the host docker socket."

Tags: docker, gitlab, kind

I am trying to run KinD in a gitlab (docker) runner. I was using the example from this gist: https://gist.github.com/trondhindenes/0307fbe9cda1164115353b4632a31ea9

I have search through gitlab ci docs but still haven't found anything about setting: "pass-thru" to the host docker socket?

Comment: I think it could mean adding `"/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"` as a volume, this means that the container can run docker commands as if it was on the host machine. Alternatively it could mean running in `host` network mode, `network_mode: host` in `docker-compose` or `--network=host`. I am almost certain though it is the first option.